# How to make an ajax call to controller action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

This is my first Ajax call, and I am really confused about what to do.

I am using ASP.NET MVC, Identity to register users in my [website](https://shopless.co.nz). Once the user is registered, I send him an email to confirm their email address.

Here is my register Action Method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email.Trim(), Email = model.Email.Trim(), FirstName = model.FirstName.Trim(), LastName = model.LastName.Trim() };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            // Send an email with this link
            string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            Email email = _emailBuilder.BuildConfirmationEmail(new MailAddress(model.Email.Trim(), model.FirstName.Trim() + " " + model.LastName.Trim()), callbackUrl, model.FirstName.Trim());
                    
            Session[SessionKeys.NewAccountConfirmationEmail.ToString()] = email;
            await _emailService.SendEmailAsync(email);

            return RedirectToAction("NewAccountCheckYourEmail");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay the form
    return View(model);
}
```

The register method sends the confirmation email and redirects to NewAccountCheckYourEmail View and the user sees this page:

[image]

and here is the Action method to redirect users to confirm your email page

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
public ViewResult NewAccountCheckYourEmail()
{
    return View();
}
```

What I want to do is to store the email in the user session, so if the user clicks on resending the email, I resend the email.

I want to make an ajax call, so when the user clicks on resend link, it posts back to the controller, gets the email from the user session, resends it and redisplays the same view.

**And I am not sure how to do this**

What I have tried is to make this AJAX call:

```
$("#ResendEmailLink").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Account/NewAccountCheckYouEmail",
        datatype: "text",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#testarea').html("All OK");
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#testarea").html("ERROR");
        }
    });
});
```

And I want it to hit this Action Method:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> NewAccountCheckYourEmail()
{
    Email email = Session[SessionKeys.NewAccountConfirmationEmail.ToString()] as Email;
    await _emailService.SendEmailAsync(email);
    return View();
}
```

But since I already have another Action method with the same name, I cannot add it... I guess what I am trying to do does not make much sense, any suggestion on a reasonable approach to achieve this?

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page. If you want to redirect then do not use ajax

Comment: Thanks again Stephen, I want to stay on the same page... so user click on resend email link, I resend the email and show the same page. Do you believe Ajax call is not suitable for what I am trying to do?

Comment: If you want to stay in the same page,then yes ajax is the correct approach, but in that case what do you want to do? You could return a `JsonResult` with some kind of message to be update in the current page for example, but at the moment your method is returning a view which does no make sense

Comment: So the ajax call has this sucess condition,  success: function (data) {
        $('#testarea').html("All OK");
    }, all I want to do is that on sucess show All OK message on the same page

Comment: Or what would be the sensible approach to send the 'email resent' message to the same view when called from AJAX?

Comment: Then your POST method should be returning a `JsonResult` (say `return Json(true);` if successful, and then you could use say `if(data) { $('#testarea').html("All OK") }`, but you need to also use `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160601/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-sarhang).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Stephen Muecke pointed out to return `Json` data, so this basic change should work.

**Resend Email Script:**

```
$("#ResendEmailLink").click(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Account/ResendEmailToUser",
    datatype:'json',
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {

if(data) { $('#testarea').html(data.Message) };

    },
    error: function () {
        $("#testarea").html("ERROR");
    }
});
```

});

**Resend Email Action Method:**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ResendEmailToUser()
{

Email email = Session[SessionKeys.NewAccountConfirmationEmail.ToString()] as Email;
await _emailService.SendEmailAsync(email);

var jsonData = new { Message = "Done!, We have Resend the Email" };

return Json(jsonData);

}
```

Comment: what is ***#testarea*** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet , Thats's the `ID` of html element which OP mentioned. Kindly read the code in the question.